# Installing Cultbook open source on xampp

Tags: php, open-source, xampp

I am trying to install this open source system called 'cultbook' onto my xampp server. Ive placed the necessary directory under htdocs as instructed. But when I try to load the page, it gives me the following error:

**Fatal error: Cannot re-assign auto-global variable _POST in C:\xampp\htdocs\cultbooking\Sessionmaincomponent\cultbooking.maincomponentNS.maincomponentImpl.class.php on line 242**

When I open the file and check the message on like 242, this is what it says (under php tags):

**public function BookingMessage($_POST,$hoteldescarr,$lang,$customarr)**

Can some one give me clues as to what might be the problem and how do I solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a global variable like $_POST or $_SESSION as a function argument any more in PHP 5.4, check the link below

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54657

You need to assign the $_POST array to any other array variable and then pass it as an parameter to the function

$_POSTARR = $_POST

public function BookingMessage($_POSTARR,$hoteldescarr,$lang,$customarr)